# Index value 0 to 8 could be out of prefix range 1 to 8 - VHDL

Tags: vhdl, synthesizer

In my code I'm defining this vector:

```
Data: in std_logic_vector(1 to 8);
```

So I have an input 0:7 and I solve a counter problem when it reaches 0. But my Synthesizer gives me this warning:

> Index value 0 to 8 could be out of prefix range 1 to 8

It can create errors? Or it just warns that if I use index 0, it can create errors?

Comment: Please include more code so we can see exactly what you've done.

Comment: Please close some of the questions you asked by choosing the "accepted answer" before asking more questions. You asked 15 questions, most of them with answers, none of them accepted. See the help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are indexing your vector with a value that has 9 values  in its range (such as `signal index : integer range 0 to 8`), but your vector only has 8 values (so you need `signal index : integer range 1 to 8`). If you post the code where you use `in`, and the declarations for any signals/values involved in indexing, we can provide more details.

Comment: Yes, I've done that. This is my counter "signal Counter : integer range 0 to 8 := 8;" but I never assign value "0" to Data(Counter); This can be a problem?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm saying. If your vector only has a range of 1 to 8, your index (`counter`) *must* have a matching range.

Comment: integer ranges are defined by the range of values, not the bits. So when you define an `integer range 0 to 8` you are defining a signal with 4 bits (b1000=8), not a 9 bit signal as you might be expecting